# Messy SO interface on Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, firefox

I have realized that something happened with SO design but last few hours I'm having hard time to read some comments.

[image]
[screenshot from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986763/use-return-from-while-cycle/27986827)

I use the latest Firefox only and can't tell does this happen with other browsers. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

**Note:** Just installed Chrome, looks normal there.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure we had this problem before the UI update.  Comments have always had a hard time with huge code blocks.

Comment: @iCodez, to be honest, this is first time I'm facing this issue.

Comment: I've never seen this before (and I always use Firefox).  (And my box shows the same mucked-up image on that page as above.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was caused by a white-space: pre-wrap css in <code>. I have removed it for when the code block is in a comment. The change will go live after our next production build.