# I see not wrapping comments on Firefox 42.0

Tags: bug, design, firefox

I see not wrapping comments on Firefox 42.0. Take a look at [this answer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24296965/447156).

[image]

There is no problem on IE 11 and Google Chrome 47.0.2526.80m versions. I search on MSO as [comment wrap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=comment%20wrap) and only related question I found is [Messy SO interface on Firefox](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283753/447156) which is tagged as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). And Jin♦ [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283888/447156) as;

> This was caused by a white-space: pre-wrap css in `<code>`. I have
>   removed it for when the code block is in a comment. The change will go
>   live after our next production build.

Since this answer belongs January 2015, I *assume* there were at least one production build since then but that doesn't seems to fix this.

Comment: Sorry about "waking up" this question but this _doesn't_ seems as fixed.

Comment: Also a problem in Web in Ubuntu